# MongoDB java driver: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient

Tags: java, ant, classpath

After I included the jar lib in ant build.xml, I still got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient
```

My ant related configuration are as below:

```
<target name="compile" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${classes}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" includeantruntime="false" debug="on">
        <classpath id="classpath">
            <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
            <fileset dir="lib">
                <include name="mongo-2.10.1.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
```

The "include" part stuff is working, because with out the include part or even I change the pathname a little bit, I will get symbol not found errors, which means currently the classpath is truly included into the file. But why it still does not work, anyone gets some idea?

And by the way, it is the first line of my java codes get the error:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
```

Even not getting to the insert and querying operations.....

Comment: Do you mean you get this exception during compile? If you get this exception during running, please check that classpath or post that target.

Comment: Sorry guys, you are right, actually it is because I do not config the jar command correctly, nothing to do with javac command

Answer (score 1):

You've only shared your "compile" target here - if you've only added the mongo jar file to the compile target, when you actually run you're going to be missing the dependency.

Check that the mongo jar is also on the runtime classpath - this might be configured in the "java" ant target, depending upon your application.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to directly check your mongo-java-driver-XXX.jar file.  Older builds do not have the class com.mongodb.MongoClient.  You can substitute Mongo instead.

Instead of

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
```

Type this:

```
Mongo client = new Mongo();
```